# Is there a way to force non-overlapping points in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data that has few points (n<10 per group), and I need to plot them as dots (per arbitrary requirement).  I am using position_jitterdodge to separate the groups and points at the same time, but because jitter is based on adding noise, the dots aren't evenly distributed and can often overlap each other despite there only being 3 of them.  I was wondering if there was a way to make them look a bit nicer; similar to the dotplot, but without the binning.  If I use dotplot, the numbers are so close to eachother that they all fall into the same bins and then you can't tell they're different on the graph.

```
figure_one = data.frame(group_name = c("veh","veh","veh","T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","T2","T3","T3","T3","veh","veh","veh","T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","T2","T3","T3","T3"), Treatment3= c("on","on","on","on","on","on","on","on","on","on","on","on","off","off","off","off","off","off","off","off","off","off","off","off"), value = c(97.4,97.5,97.6,50.8,50.9,51.5,92.2,93.4,93.6,11.3,11.5,11.2,97.3,97.5,97.8,80.1,78.7,79.7,94.6,96.2,94.3,80.5,80,81.5))
    ggplot(figure_one, aes(y = value, x = group_name, col = Treatment3)) +  
      geom_jitter(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 1, jitter.width = 0.3, seed = 6), size = 2) +
      labs(title = "Figure 1") +
      ylab(label = "% Survival") +
      scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(figure_one$group_name)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100)) +
      theme_minimal()
```

Comment: What you are probably looking for is [geom_beeswarm](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm) which you can now get from CRAN (`install.packages('ggbeeswarm')`)

Comment: @jared_mamrot This works perfectly for what I need.  Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I'll make it an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a jittered dotplot in R, but without points overlapping, you can use `geom_beeswarm()` from the [ggbeeswarm](https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm) package. This tutorial gives a great overview / examples: https://apreshill.github.io/data-vis-labs-2018/04-distributions.html